Unable to turn off Delphi compiler warning with {$WARNINGS OFF}
To silence the warning about override mousemove event with my own I can use the 'reintroduce' keyword, but before that I just tried to use compiler directives, which did nothing. Why? What's going on here?
{$WARNINGS OFF}
procedure MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
{$WARNINGS ON}

=> [dcc32 Warning] W1010 Method 'MouseMove' hides virtual method of base type 'TControl'
ver 10.4

It isn't always obvious how to map a warning to a specific line of code/statement, especially in declarative parts of the code. Clearly the compiler doesn't support this level of granularity in this case. The documentation isn't detailed enough for us to tell if this is a bug or a lack of a nice feature. Not much more to say, really, unless you ask one of Embarcadero's Delphi compiler developers.

The real question is, why you don't mark your method with the override keyword!?

Are you sure you want to hide that method. Generally, hiding virtual methods except in rare circumstances is a really a bad idea and can easily turn into a debugging nightmare where you will wonder why is the wrong method being called in some place, and you will not realize that signature is different one.
